# How to get top 10 items from a nested json file using python?

Tags: python, json, sorting

Below is the json file data:

```
 {
        "a": [
            {
                "incl": "34.86"
            },
            {
                "excl": "34.86"
            },
            {
                "m": "tb"
            },
            ...
        ]
        "b": [
            {
                "incl": "24.86"
            },
            {
                "excl": "14.86"
            },
            ...
        ]
      ...
    }
```

This is an example of the json file,

I want to get top n item(for example , "a", "b") by incl or excl, how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Please share code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not a coding or design service -- we expect you to make the initial attempt.

Comment: Thanks, I think as the accepted answer, the x  is what I am not sure about.

Comment: @shenmufeng its good if you read more about the lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `sorted()` here, which returns a list of the keys in the desired order.
For top `n` keys by `incl` :

```
sorted(d , key = lambda x: d[x][0]['incl'],reverse = True)[:n] # n = 10
```

For top `n` keys by `excl` :

```
sorted(d , key = lambda x: d[x][0]['excl'],reverse = True)[:n]
```

Note:

- Here `d` is the json

---

If the structure can vary, like `incl` and `excl` aren't in the same order:

```
sorted(d , key = lambda x: [i['incl'] for i in d[x] if 'incl' in i] , reverse = True)
sorted(d , key = lambda x: [i['excl'] for i in d[x] if 'excl' in i] , reverse = True)
```

Comment: result = sorted(items, key=lambda i: items[i]['id'], reverse = True)[:8]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict